# Why am I not seeing my macro-created functions in the new slime session? (clojure)

Tags: macros, clojure, slime, swank

In my clojure code, I have a few functions which are created with calls to custom macros. Typically, the macros would take a data structure of some sort and create a method from it.

This is a contrived example:

```
(create-function {:name "view-data" ...})
```

which would create a new function called `view-data`. (My database queries are data-driven, so I can create a function with an indicative name that calls a specific query)

My problem is that when I run the `mvn clojure:swank` target and connect to the slime session from emacs these functions aren't visible. I have to visit the file and compile it myself with `C-c C-k` for the functions to be created.

The maven output suggests that the files themselves compile fine, but the slime session doesn't know about the functions.

Any ideas why this might be happening?

Answer (score 1):

I have a file in my project that `require`s all the namespaces which makes all the functions from every where available in the repl. perhaps there is a more slime-elegant way of doing this, but this hack has been very reliable for me.

Answer (score 1):

Note that in clojure, compiling and loading are separate steps. You can generate all the class files you like, but if they're not loaded, it won't affect the running process.

I don't know enough about clojure:swank for maven, but it sounds to me that, like leiningen, the swank target will only set up the classpath for your project and load the swank code but not any of the code in your project. So you will still have load load your code in some way after that (for instance; from Emacs/SLIME, using some other target/plugin or from the REPL).